# Convert julian to date c++

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to get the date from a julian date using this two functions that I wrote

```
int dayepoch(int amin, int acur,int mcur, int dcur){
    int daycount = 0;
    for(int a=amin;a<acur;a++){
        for(int m=mcur;m<=12;m++){
            for(int d=1;d<=daymo(a,m);d++) daycount ++; 
        }
    }
    for(int m=1;m<mcur-1;m++){
        for(int d=1;d<=daymo(acur,m);d++) daycount ++;
    }   
    for(int d=1;d<=dcur;d++) daycount ++;
    return daycount;    
}

int *dayepochrev(int amin, int e){
    int a = amin;
    int m = 1;
    int d = 1;
    while(dayepoch(amin,a,m,d) <= e) a++;
    a--;
    while(dayepoch(amin,a,m+1,d) <= e) m++;
    m--;
    while(dayepoch(amin,a,m+1,d) <= e) d++; 
    d--;
    int *epochrev = new int[3];
    epochrev[0] = a;
    epochrev[1] = m;
    epochrev[2] = d;

    return epochrev;
    delete[] epochrev;  
}
```

where

```
int daymo(int a, int m){
    int dmmax = 0;
    if((a % 4 == 0 && a % 100 != 0)||(a % 400 == 0) ) {
        if(m==0)dmmax = 0;
        if(m==1)dmmax = 31;
        if(m==2)dmmax = 29;
        if(m==3)dmmax = 31;
        if(m==4)dmmax = 30;
        if(m==5)dmmax = 31;
        if(m==6)dmmax = 30;
        if(m==7)dmmax = 31;
        if(m==8)dmmax = 31;
        if(m==9)dmmax = 30;
        if(m==10)dmmax = 31;
        if(m==11)dmmax = 30;
        if(m==12)dmmax = 31;
    }
    else {
        if(m==0)dmmax = 0;
        if(m==1)dmmax = 31;
        if(m==2)dmmax = 28;
        if(m==3)dmmax = 31;
        if(m==4)dmmax = 30;
        if(m==5)dmmax = 31;
        if(m==6)dmmax = 30;
        if(m==7)dmmax = 31;
        if(m==8)dmmax = 31;
        if(m==9)dmmax = 30;
        if(m==10)dmmax = 31;
        if(m==11)dmmax = 30;
        if(m==12)dmmax = 31;
    }
    return dmmax;
}
```

If the starting month is MOSTART = 4 and the starting year = 1945 and the number of months considered are 12, than the total number of days are

EPOCH = 365

(from 1/4/1945 to 31/3/1946) which I can get using

int EPOCH = dayepoch(1945, 1946, MOSTART,31);

which is the TOTAL NUMBER OF DAYS IN THE GIVEN PERIOD (DAYS SINCE YEAR).

Then I would like to come back to the date using the sequence 1-365 applied to the given period

```
for(int e=1;e<EPOCH+1;e++){
  epochrev = dayepochrev(amin,e);
}
```

but I get the dates 1-1-1945 -> 31-12-1945. Please can you help me to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: `return epochrev;
delete[] epochrev;` – hmm. Try to retrace what code is going to be executed here.

Comment: Commands after a return won´t be executed, because return stops the function immediately.

Comment: Ok, thanks but I don't think is this the problem but the fact that my sequence goes from 1 to 365 and not from 91 to 396 but when I try to change this I can't understand what happens.

Comment: I agree that it isn’t related to the problem you’re having but it’s a fundamental bug in your code. At any rate, for conversions between Julian and Gregorian / ISO calendar, have a look at this reference implementation: http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/date_algorithms.html#Example:%20Converting%20between%20the%20civil%20calendar%20and%20the%20Julian%20calendar